# Why can't TypeScript infer the correct function and types to be used from an object?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

For example, I have the following discriminated union:

```
interface InputType<T> {
  _type: string;
  param: T;
}

class AInput implements InputType<number> {
  param: number;
  _type: "a";
}

class BInput implements InputType<number> {
  param: number;
  _type: "b";
}

class CInput implements InputType<string> {
  param: string;
  _type: "c";
}
```

(This is just a minimal example; you can imagine that there are lots more input types.)

I also have a "map" from the type to the handler.

```
const handlers = Object.freeze({
  a: (n: number) => n + 1,
  b: (n: number) => n * 2,
  c: (s: string) => "Hello " + s
});
```

(I didn't use `Map` here because I cannot find a way to completely maintain the type information. You can also imagine that the handlers are pretty complicated and exist in separate files / modules.)

When I try to use this handler like this:

```
const input: AInput | BInput | CInput = parseInput("42");
handlers[input._type](input.param);
```

I get a compilation error that:

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Why did TypeScript had to do intersection of the input types and infer `never`? Why can't it infer that the correct function will be called with the correct parameter type?

Additionally, what's the workaround for this?

Related TS playground: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQzAEwDYFMBOEYF4YDyARgFbrBQB0AZpuugF7oAUA3gLABQMMCAXDGZgBYAK4BbIlgCUeAHwwwMANQwAjABouPIgKEiJUzLNwKlAKhgAmLdxjA9EAdEwBLMAHMTCgEQAJdFRUEBgfFRgILgBfaQBuLi53KCxqBGB0GABJMAAHUSgAFQBPHPQAHgKFDjsAfSgS9GcoN094uxyETARxAQK2qITOYFQECBwAQWy82FdxHIxxdDAoHCn84tKysUksKu0YDq6exUMsNp46hoEfBB82-dBIZtEKEEw2Q%206ogVZP4%202jDEYNUeDwoHBXBBKH88AdOt1zqDwZDKJdSrCbnd9gNODiuMNRjgAEJrGZzBZLFZZXLrBpbU6YPbteH-BmItGNUJELGcB7gFwvKBvD4s77Av4GHaYIEgpEQqEw-B-RFg%20Wo%20ro-A%20bmInF4oYjMYwADCpJgs3m6EWy1WNMKdJc7g8TJ4EoizSd7I1nJ8wB5fKemEFwt%20op%20bsdnhl%201VKMVcKOKpgyKhHIxft10UG1FEYAornACYg6FJzAAbghUKJOZGvAJJnaYAAfGAkxst02N2WuaiCACEADkGZRIdlkh4sOXK9XpLJZTxHtATuJYYdi2Op1X0HEY%20be0IJDA5PgAAxz3c8OhQUSYJRgdAAdxgDembAvoLd23fMSTURggWLYF3yvG870fVtS3nUFXRZSVvx3OweBxJD-1QQCoJA29FHAztXygmCjgECst13H9sSzXkhn5GZGyVTp1ztZgfAAFisHwEK4RAUAwbAAG13GmdUGgAXWYAT8mhFk4hgAB6GSYAAdTgIoAH4gA)

Comment: Hey looks like another example of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  When I get off mobile I’ll link to an answer.

Comment: See the answers to the other questions; this is a limitation of TypeScript.  It can only analyze any given piece of code once, and it doesn't track potential correlations.  The workarounds are to either be safe-but-redundant or convenient-but-unsafe, as shown in the other answers, and [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WolZPw) of your example code.  Good luck!